# Jenkins build fails when unpacking Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm learning how to work with Jenkins, running it locally on my computer with Apache Tomcat. I've made a basic build for a Maven project, but bumped into a problem. The build fails because somehow it can't unpack Maven. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Unpacking https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip to C:\Users\Nina\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven on Jenkins
java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.positionAtEndOfCentralDirectoryRecord(ZipFile.java:780)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:716)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:461)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:192)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:152)
    at hudson.FilePath.unzip(FilePath.java:642)
    at hudson.FilePath.unzip(FilePath.java:633)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$200(FilePath.java:211)
    at hudson.FilePath$UnzipFrom.invoke(FilePath.java:622)
    at hudson.FilePath$UnzipFrom.invoke(FilePath.java:615)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.FilePath.unzipFrom(FilePath.java:613)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:927)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to unpack https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip (9602303 bytes read of total 9602303)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:931)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip to C:\Users\Nina\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:937)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:850)
    at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:77)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:69)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.tasks.Maven$MavenInstallation.forNode(Maven.java:662)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.getEnvironment(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:185)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1165)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1880)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'll include the pom.xml I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.vdab</groupId>
    <artifactId>GoedeDoel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Goede doel</name>
    <description>Goede doel</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried manually installing Maven into the folder, but that doesn't seem to help. I've tried googling for existing queries of this kind of problem, but no luck. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction for a solution.

Comment: First I recommend not to use Tomcat just use plain war file of Jenkins second the problem looks like a download issue (network?) with ZIP file...